# Работа с SQL и PHP

Tags: php, mysql

У меня система регистрации и входа. Я добавил uniqueID-это как бы с помощью функции rand дает input value и отправляется вместе с email-ами так далее.Я хочу чтобы когда я буду вводить тот uniqueID (rand)на определенном странице ччтобы  там была отображена email password так далее(Но именно те которые в странице регистрации были отправлены вместе думаю поняли).Как можно это сделать я новичок еще. Спасибо заранее!

```
div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputTime">Unique ID(восст пароля)</label>                
            <div class="input-group clock">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
            </span>
            <input name="uniqueID"type="text"value="echo rand(10000,99999);?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Bio"disabled>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо сделать форму в с двумя полями `input` с типами `text` и `submit`. Полям дать имена и так далее, в php подключится к базе — записать в переменные пришедшие данные.

Сформировать запрос:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM название таблицы WHERE uniqueID='переменная в которой хранится uniqueID который ты ввел'";
    $result = mysqli_query(переменная, в которую ты запихнул подключение,$query);
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    for($i = 0;$i<$rows;$i++){
        $user = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        //тут выводишь любым удобным для тебя способом:
        echo "mail: $user".[0]." password: ".$user[1]."/n";
    }
```

Comment: ... И тут же первый забредший хакер меняет пароль админа, потому что в запросе sql-инъекция, и можно получить любого пользователя. _Никогда_ не подставляйте и тем более не рекомендуйте подставлять значения переменных непосредственно в текст запроса ! _Всегда_ используйте (и рекомендуйте использовать) подготавливаемые выражения и привязку переменных http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Я по ссылке посмотрел не понял очень можете объяснить подробнее? Так его код работает то что я хочу просто хотел бы узнать вы что имели в виду